# Как выводить сообщение ошибки пользователю?

Tags: java, android, json

Имеется приложение, которое получает данные JSON через (GET). Вопрос: как выводить сообщение ошибки пользователю, если приложение не может подключиться к серверу (допустим, неверный адрес) или неверно был указан GET?
Пробовал выводить через try, catch, finally, но приложение крашится и выдаёт ошибку - `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`
Вот мой код:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    SharedPreferences dwonloadbd;
    EditText server;
    EditText key;
    final String SAVED_HOST = "saved_host";
    String Url = "";
    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    TextView processing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        server = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.url);
        key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.key);
        processing = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Texterrors);
        loadText_host();
        server.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                            saveText_host();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );

        Button asd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Download);
        asd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //new RequestTask().execute("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json");
                if (server.getText().length() != 0) {
                    if (key.getText().length() != 0) {
                        if (checkEnternet() == true) {
                            Url = String.valueOf("http://"+server.getText().toString()) + "/api/equipment.php?key=" + String.valueOf(key.getText().toString());
                            Equipment.deleteAll(Equipment.class);
                            new ParseTask().execute();
                            processing.setText("Загрузка базы даннных, пожалуйста подождите..");
                        }else{Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Интернет не подключен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                    }else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Поле (ключ) не заполненно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Поле (Адрес сервера) не заполненно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            }
        });

    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resultJson = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Не удалось подключиться к серверу", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String secondName = "";

            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strJson);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i ++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    /*if (obj.getString("name").equals("монитор 19 Samsung 943N")) {
                        dataJsonObj = obj;
                        break;
                    } */
                    Equipment equipment_add = new Equipment(obj.getString("name"), obj.getString("invertory_number"), obj.getString("serial_number"), obj.getString("place"), obj.getString("owner"));
                    equipment_add.save();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Name: " + obj.getString("name") + obj.getString("invertory_number"));
                }
                processing.setText("Загрузка завершена.");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        }
    }

    private void saveText_host() {
        dwonloadbd = getSharedPreferences("host", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor host = dwonloadbd.edit();
        host.putString(SAVED_HOST, server.getText().toString());
        host.commit();
    }

    private void loadText_host() {
        dwonloadbd = getSharedPreferences("host", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedTexthost = dwonloadbd.getString(SAVED_HOST, "");
        server.setText(savedTexthost);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveText_host();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    public boolean checkEnternet(){
        ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что обращение к UI элементам из другого треда запрещено, оттуда у вас и проблемы. Есть как минимум 3 способа решения этой проблемы:

1) Самый правильный: завершить `doInBackground()` и обработать ошибку в `onPostExecute()` - там можно обращаться к UI элементам

2) Не очень красивый. Вызвать:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run(){
        // вызвать Toast здесь
      }
   })
```

3) Чуть более красивый. Через `Handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == 1) {
       //Toast здесь
    }
}
};
```

и далее уже при ошибке вызвать:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```